# Filtering dataset based on conditional time range from another dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

I currently have two sample datasets: `score` and `status`. In the real dataset, there are more than two people.

**Data**

`score`

```
Person      Score ScoreDateTime
Person A    18    12/6/2020 5:06        
Person A    18    12/6/2020 8:00        
Person A    20    12/7/2020 7:40        
Person B    18    12/27/2020 1:56       
Person B    19    12/27/2020 20:00      
Person B    18    12/28/2020 20:00      
Person B    20    12/29/2020 20:00
```

`status`

```
Person      Status   StatusDateTime
Person A    Woke up  12/7/2020 2:00     
Person A    Woke up  12/7/2020 4:00     
Person A    Woke up  12/7/2020 6:00     
Person A    Woke up  12/7/2020 8:00     
Person A    Woke up  12/7/2020 10:00        
Person B    Woke up  12/27/2020 5:00        
Person B    Woke up  12/28/2020 2:00        
Person B    Woke up  12/28/2020 4:00        
Person B    Woke up  12/28/2020 22:00       
Person B    Woke up  12/28/2020 23:59
```

I want to filter `status` to only keep rows that are in between the `ScoreDateTimes` where the `Score` is less than 19.

The time range should be from when the `Score` is less than 19 to up until when the `Score` is 19 or greater. So:

- For Person A, I want all rows that are between 12/6/2020 5:06 - 12/7/2020 7:40
- For Person B, I want all rows that are between 12/27/2020 1:56 - 12/27/2020 20:00 and 12/28/2020 20:00 - 12/29/2020 20:00

**Desired `status` dataset**

```
Person      Status   StatusDateTime
Person A    Woke up  12/7/2020 2:00     
Person A    Woke up  12/7/2020 4:00     
Person A    Woke up  12/7/2020 6:00  
Person B    Woke up  12/27/2020 5:00   
Person B    Woke up  12/28/2020 22:00       
Person B    Woke up  12/28/2020 23:59
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated (and a dplyr approach would be awesome).

**Code**

```
score <- structure(list(Person = c("Person A", "Person A", "Person A", 
"Person B", "Person B", "Person B", "Person B"), Score = c(18L, 
18L, 20L, 18L, 19L, 18L, 20L), ScoreDateTime = c("12/6/2020 5:06", 
"12/6/2020 8:00", "12/7/2020 7:40", "12/27/2020 1:56", "12/27/2020 20:00", 
"12/28/2020 20:00", "12/29/2020 20:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

status <- structure(list(Person = c("Person A", "Person A", "Person A", 
"Person A", "Person A", "Person B", "Person B", "Person B", "Person B", 
"Person B", "Person B", "Person B"), Status = c("Woke up", "Woke up", 
"Woke up", "Woke up", "Woke up", "Woke up", "Woke up", "Woke up", 
"Woke up", "Woke up", "Woke up", "Woke up"), StatusDateTime = c("12/7/2020 2:00", 
"12/7/2020 4:00", "12/7/2020 6:00", "12/7/2020 8:00", "12/7/2020 10:00", 
"12/27/2020 5:00", "12/28/2020 2:00", "12/28/2020 4:00", "12/28/2020 22:00", 
"12/28/2020 23:59", "12/29/2020 2:00", "12/29/2020 22:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: Please provide additional details on your criteria. For example, why are scores of 18 included when they are interrupted by 19? What happens if there are 3 scores of 18? What about 4?

Comment: Basically, the `score` dataset is a record of the reassessments done for the Person. If there are multiple scores less than 19, the time range will go from the time of the earliest one up until the time of when the score is 19 or greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a `data.table` approach

```
library(date.table)
# Sample data -------------------
score <- fread("Person      Score ScoreDateTime
PersonA    18    12/6/2020T5:06        
PersonA    18    12/6/2020T8:00        
PersonA    20    12/7/2020T7:40        
PersonB    18    12/27/2020T1:56       
PersonB    19    12/27/2020T20:00      
PersonB    18    12/28/2020T20:00      
PersonB    20    12/29/2020T20:00")
status <- fread("Person      Status   StatusDateTime
PersonA    Wokeup  12/7/2020T2:00     
PersonA    Wokeup  12/7/2020T4:00     
PersonA    Wokeup  12/7/2020T6:00     
PersonA    Wokeup  12/7/2020T8:00     
PersonA    Wokeup  12/7/2020T10:00        
PersonB    Wokeup  12/27/2020T5:00        
PersonB    Wokeup  12/28/2020T2:00        
PersonB    Wokeup  12/28/2020T4:00        
PersonB    Wokeup  12/28/2020T22:00       
PersonB    Wokeup  12/28/2020T23:59")
score[, ScoreDateTime := as.POSIXct(ScoreDateTime, format = "%m/%d/%YT%H:%M")]
status[, StatusDateTime := as.POSIXct(StatusDateTime, format = "%m/%d/%YT%H:%M")]

# Code ---------------------
score[, ScoreDateTime2 := shift(ScoreDateTime, n = 1, type = "lead") - 1, by = Person]
status[ score[ Score <= 18, ], match := 1, on = .(Person, StatusDateTime >= ScoreDateTime, StatusDateTime <= ScoreDateTime2)]
status[ match == 1,][, match := NULL][]
#     Person Status      StatusDateTime
# 1: PersonA Wokeup 2020-12-07 02:00:00
# 2: PersonA Wokeup 2020-12-07 04:00:00
# 3: PersonA Wokeup 2020-12-07 06:00:00
# 4: PersonB Wokeup 2020-12-27 05:00:00
# 5: PersonB Wokeup 2020-12-28 22:00:00
# 6: PersonB Wokeup 2020-12-28 23:59:00
```